# Event when the user changes the browser tabs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for an event that fires whenever the user switches from the page to another tab and another event that fires when the user switches to the tab again.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        console.log('Tab is hidden');
    } else {
        console.log('Tab is visible');
    }
});
```

Comment: Fortunately you can't do this. The closest you can do is [window.blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) and focus.